# Setar a largura em CSS do button para 100% quando mobile

Tags: html, css

Olá, gostaria de ajuda com um pequeno problema, apesar de parecer simples, eu não mexo muito com `CSS` por isso peço ajuda.Gostaria de setar a **largura** do meu `button` quando o site for acessado para 100% para que ele ocupe todo espaço. Acredito que a imagem ilustrará melhor:
[image: Print do Problema]

Através da Imagem vocês podem ver que os botões estão com tamanho desigual, há alguma maneira de eu consertar isso?

Comment: Poste seu código (HTML + CSS).

Comment: Aplique [Media Queries](https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/) no seu CSS para criar uma opção alternativa de layout para diferentes tipos de tela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloque media queries para solucionar esse problema.

Veja o exemplo a seguir:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     button {
       width:100%;
     }
 }
```

Neste link explica passo a passo de como podemos utilizar as media queries:
https://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/